# How to generate external v-for without element?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, multidimensional-array, v-for

i'm looking for solution for my problem.
I've got 2 arrays

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

I want to render one line in table (in `<tr>`) like that:

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="c[0][0]" value="1a"></td>
    <td><input name="c[0][1]" value="1b"></td>
    <td><input name="c[0][2]" value="1c"></td>
    <td><input name="c[0][3]" value="1d"></td>
    <td><input name="c[1][0]" value="2a"></td>
    <td><input name="c[1][1]" value="2b"></td>
    <td><input name="c[1][2]" value="2c"></td>
    <td><input name="c[1][3]" value="2d"></td>
    <td><input name="c[2][0]" value="3a"></td>
    <td><input name="c[2][1]" value="3b"></td>
    <td><input name="c[2][2]" value="3c"></td>
    <td><input name="c[2][3]" value="3d"></td>
    <td><input name="c[3][0]" value="4a"></td>
    <td><input name="c[3][1]" value="4b"></td>
    <td><input name="c[3][2]" value="4c"></td>
    <td><input name="c[3][3]" value="4d"></td>
</tr>
```

I don't know how to render it, i'm trying to use two v-if's but I have a problem because 'v-if' has to be assigned to html element. I have tried like that (don't analyze properly of using variables, just a method of rendering):

```
                <span v-for="(a_element, i) in a" :key="i">
                    <td v-for="(b_element, j) in b" :key="j">
                        <input name="`${'c['+i+']['+j+']'}`" model="c[i][j]">
                    </td>
                </span>
```

but I received sth like that:

```
<tr>
    <span>
    <td><input name="c[0][0]" value="1a"></td>
    <td><input name="c[0][1]" value="1b"></td>
    <td><input name="c[0][2]" value="1c"></td>
    <td><input name="c[0][3]" value="1d"></td>
    </span>
    <span>
    <td><input name="c[1][0]" value="2a"></td>
    <td><input name="c[1][1]" value="2b"></td>
    <td><input name="c[1][2]" value="2c"></td>
    <td><input name="c[1][3]" value="2d"></td>
    </span>
    <span>
    <td><input name="c[2][0]" value="3a"></td>
    <td><input name="c[2][1]" value="3b"></td>
    <td><input name="c[2][2]" value="3c"></td>
    <td><input name="c[2][3]" value="3d"></td>
    </span>
    <span>
    <td><input name="c[3][0]" value="4a"></td>
    <td><input name="c[3][1]" value="4b"></td>
    <td><input name="c[3][2]" value="4c"></td>
    <td><input name="c[3][3]" value="4d"></td>
    </span>
</tr>
```

And it doesn't work, table won't render properly, can anybody help? How to make v-if without element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a HTML element: that's what the `<template>` tag is for. It is to be used as a placeholder:

```
<template v-for="(a_element, i) in a">
    <td v-for="(b_element, j) in b" :key="j">
        <input name="`${'c['+i+']['+j+']'}`" model="c[i][j]">
    </td>
</template>
```

NOTE: If you're using Vue3, [remember to add a key for your `<template>` placeholder tag](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html#with-template-v-for):

```
<template v-for="(a_element, i) in a" :key="i">
    <td v-for="(b_element, j) in b" :key="j">
        <input name="`${'c['+i+']['+j+']'}`" model="c[i][j]">
    </td>
</template>
```